# For any function $f$ in $L^2(-π,π)$, is it true that $||f||_{L^2}$ $\leq$ $C||f||_{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For any function f in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, is it true that $||f||_{L^2}$ $\leq$ $C||f||_{inf}$ ?

I came up with this question because in *An Introduction to Hilbert Space* by N.Young, right before corollary 5.4, it's stated that $||f||_{L^2}$ $\leq$ $C||f||_{\infty}$, where C a constant, for all continuous function on $(-π,π)$.

Comment: Hint: Suppose $\|f\|_\infty = 1$.  Then $|f(x)| \le 1$ for almost all $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$ (everywhere except possibly a set of measure zero).  What can you conclude about $\|f\|_{L^2}$?  This holds regardless of whether $f$ is continuous, as long as it's $L^2$-integrable.

Comment: Yeah I probably get it. Since in the book the author says: integral of |f|^2dx from -pi to pi $\leq$ |g|_inf^2*2pi

Comment: I was just not sure if I can apply the similar argument to all function in L^2. I am not too familiar with Lebesque integrals